# Performance Python: How should I structure time series analysis modules?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

**Question**

Let's assume the following `DataFrame` is given

```
ID               IBM      MSFT      APPL      ORCL       FB       TWTR
date                                                                     
1986-08-31   -1.332298  0.396217  0.574269 -0.679972 -0.470584  0.234379   
1986-09-30   -0.222567  0.281202 -0.505856 -1.392477  0.941539  0.974867   
1986-10-31   -1.139867 -0.458111 -0.999498  1.920840  0.478174 -0.315904   
1986-11-30   -0.189720 -0.542432 -0.471642  1.506206 -1.506439  0.301714   
1986-12-31    1.061092 -0.922713 -0.275050  0.776958  1.371245 -2.540688
```

and I want to do some operations on it. This could be some complicated mathematical method. The columns are structurally the same.

**Q1:** What is the best method wrt. performance and/or implementation design?

**Q2:** Should I program a method that is disassembling the `DataFrame` into numerical parts ( `numpy` arrays ) and indices?  Thereby the necessary calculations would be undertaken by a submodule on the `numpy` array. The main method would be only responsible for recollecting the data retrieved from the submodule and rejoining it with the corresponding indices ( see example code below ).

```
def submodule(np_array):

    # some fancy calculations here

    return modified_array


def main(df):
    cols = df.columns
    indices = df.index
    values = df.values()

    modified_values  = submodule(values)
    new_df =  pd.DataFrame(modified_values, columns=cols, index=indices)
    return new_df
```

**Q3:** Or should I do the calculations with `DataFrames` directly?

**Q4:** Or should I work with objects instead?

**Q5:** What is better with respect to performance, design, or code structure?

---

**Addendum**

Some more practical example would be if I want to do a portfolio optimization.

**Q6:** Should I pass the whole `DataFrame` into the optimization or use only the numerical matrix. Strictly speaking I don't think that the information of the `DataFrame` should be passed to a numerical method. But I am not sure whether my thinking is outdated.
Another example would be calculating the `Delta` for a number of options ( an operation on every single series instead of a matrix operation )

P.S.:
I know that I wouldn't need to use a separate function for disassembling. But it highlights my intentions.

Comment: Well if the functions are supported by pandas directly, why would you pull out arrays, do transformations and pass it back in to the dataframe? It's impossible, I think,  to answer this. You need to use `timeit` and see.

Comment: This is too high-level. If you want speed then you need to use vectorized approaches, which are supported in pandas and numpy, and avoid python objects and `for` loops. You then need to see whether you do calculations on views or whether you create copies of objects (which is slower).

Comment: **Do not hesitate to be Quantitative right from the problem formulation, ok?** -- how many [us] does ***"some operations"*** last per 1E6 column-elements at the moment ( **the Performance as-is** baseline )? **Next: what is your target performance / duration [us/1E6] data-cells?** With all due respect, **without this pair of facts, there is no sense to start any opinionated talk-show, the less a serious Quant Project**, is there?